Assign value based on another
There are 2 input tables, objective is to assign value in Table 1 based on Previous ID & Next ID mapping present in Table 2
Edited Input Table 1:



ID
value




123
null


456
null


789
maths


246
english


135
chemistry


76899
null



Edited Input Table 2:



Previous ID
Next ID




246
123


135
456


123
123


456
456



Edited Output:



ID
Value




123
english


456
chemitry


789
maths


246
english


135
chemistry


76899
null



For example, for ID 123, it's previous ID 246 has a value of english in Table 2, hence the same should be assigned to ID 123 in value column of Table 1
Edit: It would good to have a select based solution instead of Update/Merge, thanks!

How many levels deep can this go?  n?   Could previous ID 123 with next ID of 012 which is also null and you'd want to see english so it's 2 nulls? you only show one level which a coalesce joins could handle.  Also what have you tried; as stated joins and a coalesce would make this work.

You can use an OUTER JOIN:
SELECT t1.id,
       COALESCE(p.value, t1.value) AS value
FROM   table_1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         table_2 t2
         INNER JOIN table_1 p
         ON (t2.previous_id = p.id)
       )
       ON (   t1.id = t2.next_id
          AND t2.previous_id != t2.next_id )

or:
SELECT t1.id,
       COALESCE(p.value, t1.value) AS value
FROM   table_2 t2
       INNER JOIN table_1 p
       ON (t2.previous_id = p.id)
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN table_1 t1
       ON (   t1.id = t2.next_id
          AND t2.previous_id != t2.next_id )

or a correlated sub-query:
SELECT t1.id,
       COALESCE(
         ( SELECT p.value
           FROM   table_2 t2
                  INNER JOIN table_1 p
                  ON (t2.previous_id = p.id)
           WHERE  t1.id = t2.next_id
           AND    t2.previous_id != t2.next_id
         ),
         t1.value
       ) AS value
FROM   table_1 t1

Or, if you can have multiple levels of previous_id/next_id pairs then you can use a hierarchical query:
SELECT t1.id,
       COALESCE(
         ( SELECT p.value
           FROM   table_2 t2
                  INNER JOIN table_1 p
                  ON (t2.previous_id = p.id)
           WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
           START WITH
                  t1.id = t2.next_id
           AND    t2.previous_id != t2.next_id   
           CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                  PRIOR t2.previous_id = t2.next_id
           AND    t2.previous_id != t2.next_id
         ),
         t1.value
       ) AS value
FROM   table_1 t1

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_1 (ID, value) AS
SELECT 123, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 76899, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789, 'maths' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 246, 'english' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 'physics' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6789, 'biology' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 135, 'chemistry' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table_2 (Previous_ID, Next_ID) AS
SELECT 246, 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 135, 456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 6789 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6789, 6789 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 456, 456 FROM DUAL;

All output:



ID
VALUE




123
english


456
chemistry


76899
null


789
maths


246
english


1234
physics


6789
physics


135
chemistry




If you want to UPDATE the table (rather than just SELECTing from the table) then you can use either of the correlated sub-queries from my 3rd or 4th suggestions and use that in the UPDATE. For example:
UPDATE table_1 t1
SET value = COALESCE(
              ( SELECT p.value
                FROM   table_2 t2
                       INNER JOIN table_1 p
                       ON (t2.previous_id = p.id)
                WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
                START WITH
                       t1.id = t2.next_id
                AND    t2.previous_id != t2.next_id   
                CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
                       PRIOR t2.previous_id = t2.next_id
                AND    t2.previous_id != t2.next_id
              ),
              t1.value
            );

Would update the table even when there are multiple levels of indirection in table_2.
fiddle

Thanks @MT0, sorry my actual data has one more case which I have probably missed to add in the question, have edited the input & output now, also you can use this fiddle to see updated input, could you please help with the updated input case, thanks again!

@RavenSmith Updated for the new data.

Thank you @MT0, but there is one catch here which I've worked out in (fiddle)[https://dbfiddle.uk/t-J-545e] here, so ID 6789 must have 'physics' as value instead of 'biology', is it possible to fix this please?

@RavenSmith Updated again.

If it is updating table1 that you need to do:
UPDATE table1 t1
SET    t1.value = (SELECT o.value FROM   table2 t2
                                    JOIN output o on t2.previous_id = o.id
                                    WHERE t2.next_id = t1.id)
WHERE  t1.value is null
;


You could use MERGE INTO to update table_1:
MERGE INTO table_1 t
USING
  ( Select t1.ID, t1.VALUE, t2.NEXT_ID, t2.PREVIOUS_ID
    From   table_1 t1
    Inner Join  table_2 t2 ON(t2.PREVIOUS_ID = t1.ID)
  ) x ON(x.NEXT_ID = t.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.VALUE = x.VALUE
WHERE t.VALUE Is Null

Select * From table_1;

/*   R e s u l t :
 ID VALUE
--- -----------
123 english
456 chemistry
789 maths
246 english
135 chemistry  */

See the fiddle here.

From Oracle Database 23ai, you can do this with direct joins in update
create table t1 (id, value) as
select * from (
  values ( 123, null ),
         ( 456, null ),
         ( 789, 'maths' ),
         ( 246, 'english' ),
         ( 135, 'chemistry' ) 
) t ( id, value );

create table t2 (prev_id, next_id) as
select * from (
  values ( 246, 123 ),
         ( 135, 456 ),
         ( 123, 123 ),
         ( 456, 456 )
) t ( prev_id, next_id );

update t1 upd_t1
set    upd_t1.value = sel_t1.value
from   t2
join   t1 sel_t1
on     sel_t1.id = t2.prev_id 
where  upd_t1.id = t2.next_id;

select * from t1;

        ID VALUE    
---------- ---------
       123 english  
       456 chemistry
       789 maths    
       246 english  
       135 chemistry

